# Problems with unicode characters in PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, unicode, utf-8

I have a column in my UTF-8 MySQL table that is datatype 'longtext'.  When I display the string on a charset=UTF-8 page in PHP, I get a unicode character (� or U+FFFD) occasionally.  Example:

"None of these adjustments affects existing force structure or military capabilities, and the efficiencies will further enable U.S. European Command to resource high priority missions,"� Pentagon Press Secretary Navy Rear Adm. John Kirby said in the release.

I have tried wrapping my string in and html_entity_decode(), to replace the unicode character with nothing, but without much luck:

```
$content = html_entity_decode(preg_replace("/U\+([0-9A-F]{4,5})/", "", $getstory[0]['content']), ENT_NOQUOTES, 'UTF-8');
```

As a side-note, this issue doesn't occur with new data inserted into the this table column, only with older data.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What does `SHOW CREATE TABLE` display for that particular table? Your encoding might not be UTF-8 for the table and/or the column.

Comment: The charset is UTF8 and the collation is utf8_general_ci

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the encoding of your php file to utf8. This can be done in your editor, somewhere at `Tools - Character Encoding`, and change it to UTF-8.

If you can't find it, open it in notepad, and go to file - save as, and when it prompts for location to save, below of the name of the file, there will be an option to choose in what character encoding you wish to save the file.

**EDIT: 
It looks like you want to change your database charset. Go to phpmyadmin and there you can change it for your database, and for each table separately

Comment: I changed the default_charset to utf-8 in my php.ini file and have the same results.

Comment: I edited my answer. I did not refer to php.ini, but to the script file itself, although I just observed that you already done that. The next possible error is in your database.